# What is precisely an anti-linear anti-involution?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, universal-algebra, algebras, involutions

Given an arbitrary $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $A$, what should be required from a function $f:A\to A$ for it to be an anti-linear anti-involution?

As I understand “anti-linear” for $A$ as a vector space means that
\begin{gather}
\forall a_{1},a_{2}\in A: f(a_{1} + a_{2}) = f(a_{1}) + f(a_{2})\\
\forall a\in A\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: f(\lambda a) = \overline{\lambda} f(a)
\end{gather}

However I don’t still understand if it preserves product or not.

I know that for a Lie-algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ representation with highest weight anti-linear anti-involution also changes the order of elements in a bracket ($f([x,y]) = [f(y),f(x)]$), but I’m not sure how it acts on $U(\mathfrak{g})$, for example.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://static.hlt.bme.hu/semantics/external/pages/endomorfizmus/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics).html) for anti-involution:  an anti-involution is an anti-homomorphism $f$ satisfying $f^2=id$. See also [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/involution).

Comment: Thanks! It seems to me that I’ve managed to work it out. It should switch the order of a product too. Like $f(xy)=f(y)f(x)$.

Comment: Yes, an anti-homomorphism $f\colon A\rightarrow A$ satisfies $f(xy)=f(y)f(x)$, see the link.